# Red Hat - Configure rsyslog.conf to write all ssh data

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm using rsyslog.conf to get sshd logs and then write them to a separate file, sshd.log.  The code works fine but I notice that it does not write everything.  If the sshd was restarted, then data are written to the logs but if I upload a document, the data does not write to the log.  Is there a way to get the system to write everything to the logs, when it was restarted and when the file was uploaded?

Here's my code:

```
$template myTemplate,"/temp/logs/sshd.log" 
:programname, startswith, "sshd" ?myTemplate
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Romeo Ninov Thank you so much for your help.  I had to tweak it to get it working.
You need to comment out the default "sftp-server"

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -l INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by add/edit

```
Subsystem internal-sftp  -l INFO
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.  If I was to upload any files, it still won't write anything to the system log.

Comment: @user1736786, try to set it to DEBUG. And did you use small `I` or you use small `L`?

Comment: @user1736786, and did you restart the `sshd` after the edit?